# Dapper provider dependant parameter token

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

Is there a way to write parameterized sql for different providers?

Example:

```
connection.QuerySingle<string>("select name from user where id = :id", new {id = 4});
```

This would work with an oracle provider but MsSql requires "@id" as parameter.

The Dapper FAQ says:

> It's your job to write the SQL compatible with your database provider.

But how? Currently we have the following workaround:

```
$".. where id = {db.ParamToken}id"
```

But that's really ugly to write in larger SQL's.

Is there a way to have one token for all providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there a way to have one token for all providers?"

Yes, but it requires some setup.  You can retrieve useful database provider specific information from an existing `DBConnection`.  First retrieve the [DataSourceInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbmetadatacolumnnames?view=netframework-4.7.2) table from the connection:

```
DbConnection connection = GetSomeConnection();
var infoTable = connection.GetSchema(DbMetaDataCollectionNames.DataSourceInformation);
```

That table will have a single row with various provider info.  In regards to parameter naming, there will be a column named `ParameterMarkerPattern` which represents a `Regex` pattern string for validating the parameter.  If that column has data, the first character will be your `DbParameter` marker.  If the column is blank, the `ParameterMarkerFormat` can give you a string format to apply when building your parameter name.

> "But that's really ugly to write in larger SQL's".

This doesn't really get around that if you're considering directly formatting your SQL, and your workaround is already much simpler than this.  However the additional data you get from the `DataSourceInformation` should be enough for you to pass in your own string to a method of your creation, which would replace a default parameter start character (like `@`) with the proper one from the provider:

```
string sql = SqlIfy("SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = @id");
```

You can go even further with this and do the same for quoted identifiers.  You can pass in something like:

`"SELECT [Name] FROM [dbo].[SomeTable]"`

and have it come out like

`SELECT "Name" FROM "dbo"."SomeTable"`

All depending on the provider.  If you wanted to dynamically build queries on some custom base provider class, you could open an initial connection and store all of the provider specific data.  You wouldn't want to call `DbConnection.GetSchema` each time you use a connection.

SQL Server:
[image]

Oracle:
[image]

Comment: I didn't want to parse and replace the token because it can obviously appear in other elements like an email address. But your solution returns some helpful information, especially the Parameter Regex. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChrisNET wouldn't you be parameterizing any string containing an email address though?